# How to Publish Only App_Code in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, publish

I have a **website** (not web application) in **Visual Studio 2008**, Most of my changes belongs to `App_Code`. Whenever I change it I need to Publish entire solution and resend nre published verion to my customers.

Publish took about 3 hours from me so that I want to `publish only App_Code folder`.

How to Do this? Ithink it should be something like

```
MSBuild App_Code // I know this is not valid I mentiond as a way that I think may work with change
```

**Update :** will it work if I remove everything else and then publish the website, after that replace published files to previouse versions?

Comment: How do you publish right now?

Comment: @Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi, I currently publish with AspNetCompiler with command prompt, I can also publish with Visual Studio itself, it's not important how to publish, I just want to do it. Do you know any way?

Answer (score 1):

Try to publish like this.

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p "C:\WebSite1\App_Code" -u "C:\TargetPath"